# Is every free module torsion-free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Context: Ring is commutative. I mean "free" not in category sense, but rather as "has a basis". Torsion-free means that there doesn't exist $m\in M$ $m\neq 0$ such that $rm = 0$ for $r\neq 0$.

For integral domain $R$ the proof is simple, take the basis representation of $m$ as $m = \sum r_im_i$, multiply by $r\neq 0$, we have

$$rm = \sum rr_im_i$$

and the right side cannot be $0$, because $m$ is not $0$ and $R$ is integral domain. But if we remove the latter assumption, it may very well happen that $rr_i=0$ for every $i$ ($m$ still has a unique representation).

Still, I cannot find any counterexample to exploit this fact.

Comment: Hint: what is the equivalent notion for the free $R$-module $R$?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @YoungMath you mean $Z/2Z$? What also holds is that if every $m$ is a torsion element, or $M$ is a torsion module, it certainly cannot have a basis. Because every one-element set is linearly dependent. Specifically, $Z/nZ$ is a torsion module because $nm=0$

Mindlack got an answer that I incorrectly defined torsion, will need to double-check

Comment: Right. Nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two meanings of "free" that you compare are actually the same.

But you are actually not taking the right definition of "torsion" in case of a non-integral ring. In general $m\in M$ is not torsion when $rm=0$ for some $r\neq 0$, but for some $r$ which is not a zero divisor. In your "counter-example", $r$ must clearly be a zero divisor since $rr_i=0$ for some $r_i\neq 0$, so it doesn't work.

I think you can easily see with this modified definition that free modules are torsion-free.

Comment: Yeah I know they are the same, but wanted to focus on basis interpretation here. Sentence was composed in a confusing way. However, I didn't know that I incorrectly defined "torsion" and yes, I can see that free modules are torsion-free with amended definition.